# How to sort an ActiveRecord collection by a joined tables column using params[:sort] value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am currently trying to sort an ActiveRecord collection by a joined tables column, in both ascending and descending order. I am currently trying the following:

```
  def index
          #sorting logic
          
          if params[:sort]
           @one_on_ones = 
            apply_scopes(OneOnOne).by_manager(current_user.id).includes(:manager, :user).order(ordering_params(params))
            .page(params[:page])
            .per(params[:per])          
          else 
            @one_on_ones = apply_scopes(OneOnOne).by_manager(current_user.id).includes(:manager, :user).page(params[:page]).per(params[:page])
          end
            
          # add filtering logic
          render_ok(
            {
              one_on_ones: OneOnOneRepresenter.basic(@one_on_ones), total: @one_on_ones
            }
          )
        end
```

I am using a module Orderable.rb to parse the incoming params and return the field to sort by and the direction to sort by, being :asc, or :desc.

```
 def ordering_params(params)
        ordering = {}
        if params[:sort]
            sort_order = { '+' => :asc, '-' => :desc }
            sort_sign = (params[:sort] =~ /\A[+-]/) ? params[:sort].slice!(0) : '+'
            
            model = controller_name.classify.constantize

            if (model.attribute_names.include?(params[:sort]) || params[:sort] === "first_name")
               ordering[params[:sort]] = sort_order[sort_sign]
            end
        end
        return ordering 
    end
```

Here is my no column error I am getting:

```
 Rswag::Specs::UnexpectedResponse:
            Expected response code '400' to match '200'
            Response body: {"errors":"PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column \"first_name\" does not exist\nLINE 1: ...s\" WHERE \"one_on_ones\".\"manager_id\" = $1 ORDER BY \"first_nam...\n                                                             ^\n: SELECT  \"one_on_ones\".* FROM \"one_on_ones\" WHERE \"one_on_ones\".\"manager_id\" = $1 ORDER BY \"first_name\" ASC LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3"}
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rswag-specs-2.3.1/lib/rswag/specs/response_validator.rb:28:in `validate_code!'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rswag-specs-2.3.1/lib/rswag/specs/response_validator.rb:18:in `validate!'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rswag-specs-2.3.1/lib/rswag/specs/example_helpers.rb:30:in `assert_response_matches_metadata'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rswag-specs-2.3.1/lib/rswag/specs/example_group_helpers.rb:95:in `block in run_test!'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:254:in `instance_exec'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:254:in `block in run'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:496:in `block in with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:453:in `block in with_around_example_hooks'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:464:in `block in run'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:604:in `block in run_around_example_hooks_for'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:338:in `call'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.5.2/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:127:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:443:in `instance_exec'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:443:in `instance_exec'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:375:in `execute_with'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:606:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:338:in `call'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:607:in `run_around_example_hooks_for'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:464:in `run'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:453:in `with_around_example_hooks'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:496:in `with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:251:in `run'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:627:in `block in run_examples'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:623:in `map'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:623:in `run_examples'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:589:in `run'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `block in run'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `map'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `run'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `block in run'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `map'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `run'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `block in run'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `map'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `run'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:113:in `block (3 levels) in run_specs'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:113:in `map'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1835:in `with_suite_hooks'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `block in run_specs'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:77:in `report'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:111:in `run_specs'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:87:in `run'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
          # /Users/tomshamp/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
          # 
          #   Showing full backtrace because every line was filtered out.
          #   See docs for RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_exclusion_patterns and
          #   RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_inclusion_patterns for more information.
```

I have also tried hardcoding the following with no luck:

```
@one_on_ones = 
            apply_scopes(OneOnOne).by_manager(current_user.id).includes(:manager, :user).order("users.first_name" => :asc)
            .page(params[:page])
            .per(params[:per])
```

Whenever I use this controller to order the results by a field of the OneOnOne, it works fine, but any time I try to order by the :user table it brakes....

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what version of rails are you using. But in current version you should either use `order("users.first_name ASC"` instead of hash (works in my project):

```rb
apply_scopes(OneOnOne)
  .by_manager(current_user.id)
  .includes(:manager, :user)
  .order("users.first_name ASC")
  .page(params[:page])
  .per(params[:per])
```

or call `references(:user)`

```rb
apply_scopes(OneOnOne)
  .by_manager(current_user.id)
  .includes(:manager, :user)
  .references(:user)
  .order("users.first_name" => :asc)
  .page(params[:page])
  .per(params[:per])
```

see documentation for [includes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes)

Comment: i needed to remove :manager from my includes statement and then this worked.